# Subject change detection not working on page load

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Here is my `app.component.ts` (excerpt) -

```
export class AppComponent {
  _subscription;

  constructor(private themeService: ThemeService){
    themeService.getDefaultTheme();
    this._subscription = themeService.themeChange.subscribe((value) => { 
      //Some code 
    });
  }
}
```

and `theme.service.ts` (excerpt) -

```
export class ThemeService {
  themeChange: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  getDefaultTheme(){
    this.changeTheme(true);
  }

  changeTheme(val:boolean){
    //Some code
    this.themeChange.next(val);
  }
}
```

As `app-root` is my root component, the `constructor` in `app.component.ts` is called shortly after the initial page load. The `constructor` calls `getDefaultTheme()` which causes the `Subject` in `theme.service.ts` to emit an event. I am subscribing to that event back in the `this._subscription ...` part.

In short, on the initial page load, `getDefaultTheme()` should be called and the subscription should be handled as well.

But when I load the page, the `getDefaultTheme()` method is called but the subscription is not handled. I do not get any error at the compile time as well as in the run time.

I delayed the execution of `getDefaultTheme()` like

```
setTimeout(function(){
    themeService.getDefaultTheme();
}, 5000);
```

Now the subscription was handled. I suspect that the event is not ready to be subscribed at the page load. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're emitting your subject before you've registered the subscription in the constructor. Swap over the call to your subject to be after you've registered the subscription.

```
export class AppComponent {
  _subscription;

  constructor(private themeService: ThemeService){
    
    this._subscription = themeService.themeChange.subscribe((value) => { 
      //Some code 
    });
   
    // After Subscription is listening
    themeService.getDefaultTheme();

  }
}
```

Comment: So that's why setting the delay in emitting the subject was working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Subscribers to [`Subject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Subject) could only receive notifications pushed to it's source *after* the subscription. Instead you could use [`ReplaySubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject) with buffer 1. It can "hold/buffer" the current value pushed to it and emit it immediately to *future* subscribers.

```js
export class ThemeService {
  themeChange: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);

  getDefaultTheme(){
    this.changeTheme(true);
  }

  changeTheme(val:boolean){
    //Some code
    this.themeChange.next(val);
  }
}
```

While [`BehaviorSubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject) is also a viable alternative, it requires a default value during initialization:

```js
themeChange: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

Comment: @Malcor 's answer worked for me now. I am not much proficient in rxjs. Will refer to your answer after I learn rxjs fundamentals in deep.